# Getting strings from an array inside a function, located on a different php page

Tags: php, arrays, function, variables

How to get the array string values from a function and echo them separately in a table which is located in another page?

**functions.php:**

```
function get_program()
    {
        $connection = db_connect();
        $username = $_SESSION['username'];
        $query = "SELECT * FROM utilizatori WHERE username = '$username'";
        $results = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
        $array = mysqli_fetch_array($results, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        return $dateOne = $array['weekOneFirst'];
        return $dateTwo = $array['weekTwoFirst'];
    }
```

**index.php:**

```
<?php require_once 'functions.php'; ?>

<div>
<?php get_program(); ?>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>
    Week 1
    </th>
    <th>
    Week 2
    </th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
    <?php echo $dateOne; ?> // date 1 from array string here
    </td>
    <td>
    <?php echo $dateTwo; ?> // date 2 from array string here
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

It returns me errors:

> Notice: Undefined variable: dateOne in ...
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: dateTwo in ...

Comment: [**Your `get_program` function is vulnerable to SQL injection!**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are other ways to do what you are doing, but this is probably going to serve you best going forward and be more flexible:

In `get_program()` you only want 1 `return` and just return the array:

```
return $array;
```

Then in the `index.php`:

```
<?php $result = get_program(); ?>

html here

<?php echo $result['weekOneFirst']; ?>
<?php echo $result['weekTwoFirst']; ?>
```

Now you can use the function for any columns in the query.  If you want a function that only returns those two columns then:

```
$query = "SELECT weekOneFirst, weekTwoFirst FROM utilizatori WHERE username = '$username'";
```

Comment: Lol. Actually my problem was that I did not know how to call the function in a correct way. Thanks for your help. This solved the problem.

Comment: I retrieve more columns and I will stick to `select *`.